# Fetching two type of data from same API

Tags: html, reactjs, json, api

I want to use two type of data like I am making a pizza order app and I have use this api- `https://run.mocky.io/v3/ec196a02-aaf4-4c91-8f54-21e72f241b68`, I want to toggle between veg and non veg and in that api there is veg and non veg boolean. tell me how to use it in React components
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = await response.json();
const transformedVegPizzas = data.filter(f=> f.isVeg).map( /* your code */);
const transformedNonVegPizzas = data.filter(f=> !f.isVeg).map( /* your code */);
```